# How do I set the language in the racket REPL

Tags: racket

I would like to set the language that my racket REPL is using interactively, like this:

```
-> #lang typed/racket
; readline-input:15:0: read: #lang not enabled in the current context [,bt for
;   context]
; typed/racket: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]`
```

But it gives me this error:

```
-> ,bt
; typed/racket: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
```

What is my error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the terminal you can choose what language to use when you start racket:

```
racket -I typed/racket
```

Comment: is there a way to change the language once the REPL has already been started? that would be useful when launching a REPL session using, say,  `M-x racket-repl` in Emacs.