# Configure emacs to specify #lang before starting racket repl

Tags: emacs, racket

I'm often editing code in `typed/racket` which isn't in executable shape yet (unfinished code, unbalanced parens).

And I need to open repl and try out expressions in it. I think it's not possible to change `#lang` when I'm in the repl already, so is there a way I can configure emacs to open the repl in a specific lang? If I could give an argument to a command like `M-x racket-repl`, that'd be best.

This question was also [asked in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628862/how-do-i-set-the-language-in-the-racket-repl#comment49204349_18631182) but remains unanswered.

Comment: Not quite starting the repl in a `#lang`, but couldn't you just `(require typed/racket)` once the repl has been started?